# Automatically input password and username on behalf of user shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, automation, centos

I am working on CentOS 6.10.

There is a file which is not made by me, say `afile_notbyme`.

Now I have to automate stuff for the user and this file asks for the username and password when run:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/Uni-SON/
./afile_notbyme start -p 5437 -D /opt/Uni-SON_DB<<<$"Username\npassword\npassword"
```

Now when I run my script it automatically pushes `Username\npassword\npassword` inside Username isntead of just `Username` .

Whereas when I run a script which asks for username and group name this `\n` works perfectly but when there is a password field it doesn't work.

What do I do to add username and password automatically ?

> Note password is asked twice by the file that is why I wrote password twice